# likhith@dell:~/projects/edgex/edgex-compose$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-no-secty.yml up -d in edgex

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

very new to docker to world when i tried to include docker compose of edgexfoundry compose i am getting below error
likhith@dell:~/projects/edgex/edgex-compose$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-no-secty.yml up -d
`ERROR: <html>

404 Not Found

## 404 Not Found

---

nginx/1.25.3

`

How to resovled the issue

Comment: Please share your Docker Compose YAML file.